# How to find the specific record using sub query in SQL

Tags: sql-server, subquery

I have a table in my Database in which Electronics part number information is saved. Against each part number, a Datasheet is attached with the Pdf file name and with its Publication date in next column.

There are some parts where pdf with different publication date is attached and I want to find out the Latest publication date pdf file.

Below is the code that I applied:

```
(
select v_prt_nbr_spr, max(s_gph_co_date), s_gph_file_name
from export1
where v_prt_nbr_spr = '747845-4'
group by v_prt_nbr_spr, s_gph_file_name
)
```

But I am getting multiple Pdf file name instead of the latest date as I am using group by clause..

Output:

```
v_prt_nbr_spr                 s_gph_co_date           s_gph_file_name       
747845-4                      01-07-2001              TYELD00008.pdf
747845-4                      14-03-2011              TYELS72963.pdf
747845-4                      04-03-2016              TYEL-S-A0001601863.pdf
```

I want only TYEL-S-A0001601863.pdf name to show as it is the latest date pdf file.

Comment: Please format your post, its very hard to understand as it is. There is a code format option on the editor.

Comment: Seems like you want a `TOP 1` and `ORDER BY`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
select top 1 
v_prt_nbr_spr, s_gph_co_date, s_gph_file_name
from export1
where v_prt_nbr_spr = '747845-4'
order by s_gph_co_date desc
```

Comment: it won't work because `s_gph_co_date` is not in the `group by`. Just remove the `group by`, it is not needed anyway.

Comment: But if I don't want to filter by part number then? I just want to find the unique part numbers with their latest pdf file name with the publication date.

Comment: So just write the query without where condition .